# What is the mechanism behind QTableView::sortingEnabled?

Tags: qt

In Qt 5.1 `QTableView` has property `sortingEnabled` which automatically sets up used `QHeaderView` and `model`. This property was introduced in QtWidgets 4.2 so I guess that its behaviour hasn't changed a lot since then.

When `sortingEnabled == true` a click on horizontal header *somehow* invokes `sort(...)` with corresponding to current sorting indicator order.

The question is how exactly is this implemented (i.e. what signals or events are used, what are the handling functions etc.) and what part of this system is responsible for the order and precedance of ordering types (my guess is that `QHeaderView` itself determines, what is next ordering when section is clicked.

Comment: Did you already read this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#sorting ?

Comment: @vahancho I saw this the other day but forgot about some of the info. This elights subject but I'm still a bit uncertain about who is responsible for sort indicator (most likely it is set when some signal from model is emitted). Thank you for the help.

Comment: The sortingEnabled() property is responsible for sort indicator (GUI), and the QSortFilterProxyModel is reponsible for the functionality. As documentation states: `Behind the scene, the view calls the sort() virtual function on the model to reorder the data in the model.`

Comment: @vahancho so you mean that when header section is clicked, it is `QTableView` that determines what sort indicator should be set? And the documentation seems to be a little obscure about what happens _before_ call to sort(), this is the part I'm most interested in.